Flutter DioException in Mockito test: expected exception but got LoginResponse
I’m encountering an issue while testing a  `login` function in my Flutter app. I’m using `Dio` for HTTP requests and `mockito` for mocking. My test is supposed to throw a `BadRequestException(message: "Invalid credentials")` when a network response 400, but instead, it LoginResponse`.
Error message:-
package:matcher                                              expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 474:18           expect
test/data/remote/api_authentication_service_test.dart 109:9  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>

Expected: throws <Instance of 'BadRequestException'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<LoginResponse>>
   Which: threw DioException:<DioException [bad response]: null>
          stack package:mockito/src/mock.dart 560:7                                     PostExpectation.thenThrow.<fn>
                package:mockito/src/mock.dart 186:47                                    Mock.noSuchMethod
                test/data/remote/api_authentication_service_test.mocks.dart 309:14      MockDio.post
                package:task_manager/data/remote/api_authentication_service.dart 23:14  ApiAuthenticationServiceImpl.login
                test/data/remote/api_authentication_service_test.dart 111:32            main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                package:matcher                                                         expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 474:18                      expect
                test/data/remote/api_authentication_service_test.dart 109:9             main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
                package:matcher                                                         expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 474:18                      expect
                test/data/remote/api_authentication_service_test.dart 109:9             main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                
          which is not an instance of 'BadRequestException'

Unit test to login

@GenerateMocks([Dio])
void main() {
  late MockDio client;
  late ApiAuthenticationService apiService;
  const fakeLoginSuccessResponse = {
    "id": 30,
    "username": "AMeero",
    "email": "example@f.com",
    "firstName": "AMeero",
    "lastName": "Xyz",
    "gender": "male",
    "image": "https://robohash.org/Jeanne.png?set=set4",
    "token": "tokennn"
  };

  setUp(() {
    client = MockDio();

    final fakeInterceptors = Interceptors();
    when(client.interceptors).thenReturn(fakeInterceptors);

    apiService = ApiAuthenticationServiceImpl(client: client);
  });

  group('ApiAuthenticationServiceImpl', () {
    group('login', () {
      test('returns LoginResponse when successful login', () async {
        final response = Response(
          data: fakeLoginSuccessResponse,
          statusCode: 200,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
        );

        when(client.post(any, data: anyNamed('data')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => response);

        final result =
            await apiService.login(username: 'test', password: 'test');

        expect(result, isA<LoginResponse>());
      });

      test('server return token when successful login', () async {
        final response = Response(
          data: fakeLoginSuccessResponse,
          statusCode: 200,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
        );

        when(client.post(any, data: anyNamed('data')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => response);

        final result =
            await apiService.login(username: 'test', password: 'test');

        expect(result.token, isNotNull);
      });

      test('throws ServerException when DioError without response', () async {
        when(client.post(any, data: anyNamed('data')))
            .thenThrow(DioException(requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '')));

        expect(
          () async =>
              await apiService.login(username: 'test', password: 'test'),
          throwsA(isA<ServerException>()),
        );
      });

      test('throws ServerException when DioError with non-400 response',
          () async {
        final response = Response(
          statusCode: 500,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
        );

        when(client.post(any, data: anyNamed('data')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => response);

        expect(
          () async =>
              await apiService.login(username: 'test', password: 'test'),
          throwsA(isA<ServerException>()),
        );
      });

      test('throws BadRequestException when 400 status code', () async {
        final response = Response(
          statusCode: 400,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '/auth/login'),
        );

        when(client.post(any, data: anyNamed('data'))).thenThrow(DioException(
          response: response,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '/auth/login'),
          type: DioExceptionType.badResponse,
        ));

        expect(
          () async =>
              await apiService.login(username: 'test', password: 'test'),
          throwsA(isA<BadRequestException>()),
        );
      });
    });
  });
}

BaseAPIService
abstract class BaseApiService with TodoApiEndpoint {
  final Dio client;

  BaseApiService({required this.client}) {
    client.options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
      responseType: ResponseType.json,
      contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    );
    //client.interceptors.add(AuthInterceptor());
    client.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: true));
  }

  Future<T> tryRequest<T>(
    Future<Response> request,
    T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJson,
  ) async {
    try {
      Response response = await request;
      if (_isRequestSuccess(response)) {
        if (response.data != null && (response.data is Map<String, dynamic>)) {
          return fromJson(response.data);
        } else {
          throw const BadRequestException(message: "Body is null");
        }
      } else {
        throw const BadRequestException();
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response != null) {
        if (e.response?.statusCode == HttpStatus.badRequest) {
          throw const BadRequestException(message: "Invalid credentials");
        } else {
          throw ServerException(
              message: e.response?.data.toString() ?? "Unknown error");
        }
      } else {
        throw ServerException(message: e.message ?? "Unknown error");
      }
    } on ServerException catch (e) {
      throw  ServerException(message:  e.message ?? "Unknown error");
    }
  }

  bool _isRequestSuccess(Response response) =>
      response.statusCode != null && response.statusCode! ~/ 100 == 2;
}

Login before:-
Future<LoginResponse> login({
  required String username,
  required String password,
}) async {

  try {
    final response = await client.post(
      '$baseUrl/auth/login',
      data: {"username": username, "password": password},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data);
    } else {
      throw BadRequestException;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is BadRequestException) {
      throw const BadRequestException(message: "Invalid credentials");
    }
    if (e is DioException) {
      if (e.response != null) {
        if (e.response?.statusCode == 400) {
          throw const BadRequestException(message: "Invalid credentials");
        } else {
          throw ServerException(message: e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        throw ServerException(message: e.message ?? "");
      }
    } else {
      throw ServerException(message: e.toString());
    }
  }
}

Login after refactor  with use tryRequest:-
  @override
  Future<LoginResponse> login({
    required String username,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    return await tryRequest(
      client.post(
        '$baseUrl/auth/login',
        data: {"username": username, "password": password},
      ),
      (body) => LoginResponse.fromJson(body),
    );
  }

Its work before refactor .
this github repo
What is problem and how passed units test ?
How can covert body response to T Type class without use  function
(body) => LoginResponse.fromJson(body)

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!
